# What .NET control do i want to use?

Tags: .net, user-interface, controls, desktop, master-detail

What .NET control do i should i use to display this to the user?

I have 2 types of elements, a package and item. The data an item contains is id, size and status. The package can have several items (but no packages as its not a tree). It holds status and count. I can think of a 3rd column for this. I will need to right click each item or package and select commands. I should have all items within a package in a group. i would like to hide or show the items in a package if the user double clicks.

I dont know what control to use. I was thinking datagrid with a id and size column and thought i can use id as status and have some kind of tree but i dont know if thats possible. What control should i use?

Comment: also, the keywords I think you are looking for are "master detail"--that may aid your search

Comment: ok desktop--cool--what version of .net? Winforms...wpf...?

Answer (score 0):

use a regular treeview... with the status as main entry level with child nodes of Product with count as a part of the label and the item(s) as child nodes ...

something like this when fully expanded :

```
+Completed Products
  +Product [2]
     + Item 
     + Item 
+ Incomplete Products
  +Product [1]
     + Item
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of implementing this is called a Master-Detail form; if you search for this you will find many implementations. You can use the standard .Net grid controls for adding, selecting, editing, and deleting rows.

You use a pair of GridViews; in your case a master grid of packages and a second detail grid of items. Clicking a package will show all the items.